# JavaScript - Print numbers from 1 to 20

Tags: javascript

I am willing to do something pretty basic; however, I am stuck with it.
I have a table grid that it has 5 rows, each row holds 4 numbers.

It should be like the following:

```
 1 | 2 | 3 | 4
 5 | 6 | 7 | 8
 9 | 10 | 11 | 12
```

and so on... up to 20

Currently, I am running 2 for loops to get it done the table shows up, but with wrong numbers (show only from 1 to 4 on each row) I believe that I have a logic issue.

Here is what it looks now :

```
 1 | 2 | 3 | 4
 1 | 2 | 3 | 4
 1 | 2 | 3 | 4
```

Code :

```js
var div, rows, linksInRows, row, col, htmlButton;
div = $('div.container');
row = '<div class="row"></div>';
rows = 5;
linksInRows = 4;

for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  div.append(row);
}

for (i = 0; i < linksInRows; i++) {
  col = $('div.row');
  htmlButton = '<div class="col"><a class="btn btn-color" href="#" role="button">'+(i+1)+'</a></div>'
  col.append(htmlButton)
}
```

```html
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: is this homework?

Comment: @Brady nope ! I bet you could solve it !

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158438/discussion-on-question-by-folky-h-javascript-print-numbers-from-1-to-20).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You were close. A couple modifications are as follows:

- Nest the loops so you can access each element in each row efficiently
- Grab **only** the last div that was appended, currently you are grabbing all `div.row`
- You link number is equal to the row number times the number of links per row plus the index of the current link in the row plus 1 to start at 1 instead of 0.

In code, that looks like this: `linkNumber = i * linksInRows + j + 1;`

```js
var div, rows, linksInRows, row, col, htmlButton;
div = $('div.container');
row = '<div class="row"></div>';
rows = 5;
linksInRows = 4;

// nest the loops instead of making them separate
for (i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
  div.append(row);
  for (j = 0; j < linksInRows; j++) {
    // we only want the most recently created div.row, not all of them
    col = $('.container .row').last();
    // take current i * the number of links in each row, so for the first
    // row you get 0-3, second row is 4-7, etc. then add 1 to start at 1
    // instead of 0
    var linkNumber = i * linksInRows + j + 1; 
    htmlButton = '<div class="col"><a class="btn btn-color" href="#" role="button">Link '+linkNumber+'</a></div>'
    col.append(htmlButton)
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container"></div>
```